# Working with elements inside a control that is bound to a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol

I have an `ObservableCollection<string>` that is bound to an `ItemsControl` whose template is just a `Button`. The content of this button are 2 `TextBlock`. I'm trying to use the `PreviewMouseRightButtonUp` event of the button to toggle the visibility of one of the textblocks, but without being able to use xaml names for elements in the template I'm hitting a wall. Is there a way of getting to the button's content elements via `sender` in that preview event, or some other way of doing this? This is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771033/is-this-concept-of-a-button-containing-a-textbox-possible) I had that didn't quite get a usable answer (probably due to my explanation, hence this simplified example). It seems to me that what should happen is I should make a control based off button that adds a property for this toggle, but that is basically what I *thought* I had in the previous question that wasn't working. I feel like a property and trigger is what most would say is the right way to go?

xaml:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="iC" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button PreviewMouseRightButtonUp="Button_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp">
                <DockPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="normal" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

code behind:

```
ObservableCollection<string> x = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public MainWindow()
{
    x.Add("1");
    x.Add("2");
    InitializeComponent();
    iC.ItemsSource = x;
}
```

Comment: I have tried code similar to yours, and in my case `Button_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp()` is being called. Did you check with the debugger that this method really is not called? Or maybe a parent element of `ItemsControl` has `IsEnabled` set to `false`.

Comment: Not sure it is the same.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578434/find-textbox-in-a-datatemplate

Comment: @fmunkert I'm not saying the code above isn't working for me, but rather how would I use that preview event to toggle visibility (or any other property) of one of the textblocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the hidden text block "secondTextBlock", then this should work:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DockPanel dockPanel = (DockPanel)((Button)sender).Content;
    TextBlock text = (TextBlock)LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(dockPanel, "secondTextBlock");
    if (text != null)
    {
        text.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Regarding your comment below: yes, multiple instances of "secondTextBlock" will be created. See the Snoop screenshot below. But these multiple instances are OK; they do not have any negative impact.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: You can use a xaml name there, inside of an `itemscontrol`? Wouldn't that end up creating multiple textblocks with the same name?

Comment: I have answered your question above.